# iOS: Delegate callbacks won't get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, delegates

The problem is that not all the delegate methods get called.

Login.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@protocol LTLoginDelegate;

@interface LTLogin : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, weak) id <LTLoginDelegate> delegate;

-(void)commitLogin:(NSString*)login password:(NSString*)password;
-(void)login:(LTLogin*)login didBecomeActive:(BOOL)success;
-(void)login:(LTLogin*)login didFailWithError:(NSError*)error;
-(void)login:(LTLogin*)login didSuccessWithMessage:(NSString*)message;

-(void)storeLoginCredentials;

@end

@protocol LTLoginDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)storeLoginCredentials;
-(void)login:(LTLogin*)login didSuccessStoringCredentials:(BOOL)success;
-(void)login:(LTLogin*)login didFailStoringCredentials:(BOOL)success;

@required
-(void)login:(LTLogin*)login didBecomeActive:(BOOL)success;
-(void)login:(LTLogin*)login didFailWithError:(NSError*)error;
-(void)login:(LTLogin*)login didSuccessWithMessage:(NSString*)message;

@end
```

Login.m

```
@implementation LTLogin

-(void)commitLogin:(NSString *)login password:(NSString *)password {

    // >>> ....
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(login:didBecomeActive:)]) {

        [self.delegate login:self didBecomeActive:YES];
    }
}


-(void)login:(LTLogin *)login didBecomeActive:(BOOL)success {

    // >>> ....
    // Don't get called here at all!!!!!!
    [self.delegate login:self didSuccessWithMessage:@"Success"];
}

-(void)login:(LTLogin *)login didSuccessWithMessage:(NSString *)message {


}

@end
```

Controller.m

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

#if LOG == 0
    NSLog(@"This one");
#endif

    LTLogin *login = [[LTLogin alloc]init];
    login.delegate = self;
    [login commitLogin:@"john.doe@hmail.con" password:@"123123"];
}

-(void)login:(LTLogin *)login didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

#if LOG == 1
    NSLog(@"login didFailWithError: Error %@",error);
#endif

}

-(void)login:(LTLogin *)login didSuccessWithMessage:(NSString *)message {

#if LOG == 1
    NSLog(@"login didSucceedWithMessage: %@",message);
#endif

}

-(void)login:(LTLogin *)login didBecomeActive:(BOOL)success {

#if LOG == 1
    NSLog(@"login didBecomeActive");
#endif
// Gets called here only!!!!!!

}
```

didBecomeActive is not get called on Login controller. My goal is build a chain of callback methods that will call each other.

Comment: why you don't use block?

Comment: Because I want to use delegates this time.

Comment: Can you try changing the name of the method -(void)login:(LTLogin *)login didBecomeActive:(BOOL)success in Login.m class as there is a method in delegate with same name?

Comment: I think you got confused with how your code works. When you call [login commitLogin:@"john.doe@hmail.con" password:@"123123"]; from Controller.m, controller goes to the same method in Login.m. From this method control will come back to -(void)login:(LTLogin *)login didBecomeActive:(BOOL)success in Controller.m.

Comment: yes  it's working exactly as expected, why do you need chain of callbacks, i think you may have better solution instead of chaining everything.....

Comment: If you need -(void)login:(LTLogin *)login didBecomeActive:(BOOL)success in Login.m class to be called, do [login login:<appropriate object> didBecomeActive:YES];

Comment: Hey Arun. Your comment gave me the right hint. I created in the m file the methods where all the required delegates got called. Technically, changed the names of the methods. Please, compose an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @NCF you can create common delegate . i guess it would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is of caller "self.delegate" to "self". Replace the older version of commitLogin with

```
-(void)commitLogin:(NSString *)login password:(NSString *)password {

    // >>> ....
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(login:didBecomeActive:)]) {

        [self login:self didBecomeActive:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Then I don't get main controller notified.

Comment: I got "login didSucceedWithMessage: Success" message on main controller if LOG flag is on. If you want to notify for becomeActive on main controller you can add call "[self.delegate login:self didBecomeActive:YES];" to "login:(LTLogin *)login didBecomeActive:(BOOL)success" method.

Comment: Or you should move the line "[self.delegate login:self didSuccessWithMessage:@"Success"];" to method "login:(LTLogin *)login didSuccessWithMessage:(NSString *)message" and put this line  "[self.delegate login:self didBecomeActive:YES];" instead.

Answer (score 1):

The method `-(void)login:(LTLogin *)login didBecomeActive:(BOOL)success` will be called only on the current delegate. In `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` you set it to `Controller`. If you want to have more than one delegate you can use [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) or `NSNotificationCenter`. Remember to add both your controller and the LTLogin instance.

Comment: Notifications are easy solution, but I don't want them. I want good-old delegates.

Comment: You can use NSHashTable for storing more than one delegate. NSHashTable can be initialize to weakly store elements. Check this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSHashTable_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSHashTable/weakObjectsHashTable for more details